# Recommendation for Logging data in AWS Lambda

Tags: java, logging, log4j, aws-lambda

AWS lambda currently supports two ways for [logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-logging.html#java-wt-logging), when Lambda function written in Java.

- log4j
- LambdaLogger

I want to know if is their any advantage of using one logging scheme over other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

What I understood from [Aws Lambda Java Logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-logging.html) and searching around net is

- Log4J

  - pros: you can customize logs(using log4j.properties).
  - cons: it increase the size of your jar/zip as you add more dependency to your project
- LambdaLogger

  - pros: it saves memory as it is already embeded on your dependencies
  - cons: it can't be customizable

I hope that it helps!

Comment: Does LambdaLogger support log levels? I can't find them. I love the binary simplicity of Unix logging but in my corporation bloat I need to be able to support levels.

Answer (score 5):

### LambdaLogger

**pros:**  detailed Report Log

- RequestId – The unique request ID for the invocation.
- Duration – The amount of time that your function's handler method spent processing the event.
- Billed Duration – The amount of time billed for the invocation.
  – For traced requests (XRAY TraceId, SegmentId ... ).
- more ...

**cons:** only one level of log. Less configurable than Log4J

### Log4J

**pros:**
facade library to configure your log level (info, debug, error...).

**cons:** Cannot add detail report log (request ID) to your function's logs

### Best of both worlds

You can have the best of both world by `aws-lambda-java-log4j2` library
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-logging.html

#### Configuration to run both Log4j and LambdaLogger

In your  `src/main/resources/log4j2.xml` file

```
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Lambda name="Lambda">
      <PatternLayout>
          <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %X{AWSRequestId} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </Lambda>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="Lambda"/>
    </Root>
    <Logger name="software.amazon.awssdk" level="WARN" />
    <Logger name="software.amazon.awssdk.request" level="DEBUG" />
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

In your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    runtimeOnly 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j18-impl:2.13.0'
    runtimeOnly 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j2:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.0'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*In my opinion to keep it simple.*

**1.** Assume you have an application project in maven where there will be multiple maven modules. You won't be passing context.getLogger() OR context argument every time you call some other module's implementation.

**2.** If you have a single handler function with no modules and multiple classes. In this case, you can start your AWS Lambda handler function code and get the context.getLogger() to get Lambda logger.

For more info : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model-v2.html

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a popular logging framework like [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/), together with its most native implementation, [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/).

The [jlib AWS Lambda Logback Appender](https://github.com/jlib-framework/jlib-awslambda-logback) allows you to do so in your AWS Lambda functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use log4j with custom lambda appender, so that your logs can go to AWS Lambda CloudWatch. Refer to https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/master/aws-lambda-java-log4j2.